# Failed to use fastspring-ruby API

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems, bundler, payment

I am trying to use the subscription update API for ruby provided by FastSpring

https://github.com/FastSpring/fastspring-ruby

I added the following line in my Gemfile

gem "FastSpring", :git => "https://github.com/FastSpring/fastspring-ruby"

I ran bundle install and everything looked fine, but when I try to require FastSpring in my application (require 'FastSpring') I get the following error

LoadError: cannot load such file -- FastSpring

I also tried to manually build/install the gem as explained on github, but I get the same error.

Any idea what's wrong with this gem ? I am running out of solutions. The source looks simple enough to be replicated directly in my app, but I prefer to use a gem instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using rvm to manage my gems.

Comment: has the answer was helpful?

Comment: I tried to install the gem directly into my system, but it didn't work either. Points 2 and 3 are not very clear to me (I am not a Ruby expert); why do the other gems in my Gemfile are working correctly? The solution adopted was to just copy the FastSpring.rb file into my project.

Comment: I rewrote the answer, and can you issue on the command line: `bundle show bundler`, `ruby -v`, `bundle exec -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your gems isn't automatically required by `bundler`, you can choose of three points:

1. Either don't use a bundler, and install a gem directly into system, then just require the gem:

   ```
   require 'FastSpring'
   ```
2. Or use *bundler*, issue `bundle exec your_code.rb`, in which you've defined `require 'FastSpring'`, or etc:

   ```
   require 'FastSpring'
   ```
3. Or use *bundler*, but before all of require instructions, issue `Bundler.require :default`. But this point [strongly isn't recommended](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/12/5-reasons-to-avoid-bundler-require).

   ```
   Bundler.require :default
   require 'FastSpring'
   ```